# ffmpeg reduce image quality, NOT size

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I successfully made a thumbnail from video using FFMPEG.

```
ffmpeg -i 'video_location' -vf thumbnail,scale=160:120  -frames:v 1 'image_location.jpg'
```

Is there any 'ffmpeg' command to reduce image size without changing image scale??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the scale filter and use the `qscale` option

```
ffmpeg -i 'video_location' -vf thumbnail -q:v 10 -vframes 1 'image_location.jpg'
```

Experiment with the `q` value for the quality/size you want.